# How to have different code styles in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to work on several customer projects from different customers each with a different code style.
I haven't found a way to make code style settings per project only by programming language.
I tried to have several Android Studio installations. But I found only descriptions how this is possible with different versions.
I would like to have latest stable version for each customer.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For me it is the default:
[image]

the corresponding xml file is in the .idea/codeStyles folder